# Decomposition into distal and proximal

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, topological-groups, topological-dynamics

For a topological group $G$ and a bounded real- or complex-valued function $f$ on $G$, the *orbit closure* of $f$ is the pointwise closure in the space of all bounded functions on $G$ of the orbit of $f$ under right translations. For a bounded function $f$ on $G$ whose orbit closure consists of continuous functions, say that $f$ is *distal* if its orbit closure is a distal $G$-flow; say that it is *proximal* if its orbit closure is a proximal $G$-flow. See e.g. section 4.6 in Berglund, Junghenn and Milnes, "Analysis on semigroups" (1989).

Question: Is there another characterization of the functions of the form $d+p$ where $d$ is distal and $p$ is proximal? If not in general then at least for some groups?

Comment: it would be useful to at least provide references to your terminology (distal $G$-flow, proximal $G$-flow) over an arbitrary topological group – also I assume you have in mind real/complex-valued functions.

Comment: @YCor Good idea. It's done.